# What are the risks of described approach to developing web application?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

We want to write a UI that consists of HTML, Javascript (JQuery) and CSS. Although the initial starting point will be served up by a web server, there won't be any sever side templating. The browser will interact with the server via a restful interface and render its UI.

What are the risks of this approach?

Ideally I'd like a nice, straightforward javascript OO api which underneath makes http calls to the server to get JSON representations of resources.  Any suggestions as to how this could be structured?

Anyone have experience with browser side templating?

Is there a framework to make this style of development easier?

We will also be defining the server side resources and my thoughts are to follow ruby on rails conventions. For example, if you define a Users resource in routes.rb, you have 7 uri templates. Any thoughts?

By the way, the server side functionality will be developed in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have plenty of experience with this approach. I can guarantee you that it works - how well in the long run, I don't know yet but I'm extremely happy with it (as a developer).

You do need to make sure that you've mastered Javascript. Read up on the state of the art, at least check Douglas Crockford's work, and most notably JSLint.

As for frameworks, this is where your vision comes in. We've built one from scratch because we need a combination of tools that existing frameworks don't and because we think we have the vision and expertise to carry it through. You have to compare the pro's and con's. If you use an existing framework you have very little control over it's direction or the speed at which bugs are found and fixed. If you build one yourself you could run the risk of making wrong decisions and ending up with a framework that doesn't quite work.

I have noticed that in our applications the custom server side code is only very small. This means the importance of the backend is only very small (validation, sanity, authorization). We use PHP, but simply because we have loads of experience with PHP.

There are definitely risks. In the startup and early transition I have noticed that 'lesser' programmers have trouble catching up. There is a very steep learning curve for anyone not too familiar with Javascript and it's many elegances.

Another risk is performance. We're advising our customers to use Google Chrome, simply because

And then there is compatibility. The idea of a framework is that it's able to hide this complexity. Luckily browsers are increasing in-tune in accordance to standards but backwards compatibility with (for instance) IE6 is incredibly difficult.

I would advise against using jQuery. I find jQuery more of a 'plugin' than an actual framework. jQuery really shines when you have a website and you want to sprinkle on some fanciness. It has some very good general tools (DOM manipulation and all that) but it's very lacking in the business-modeling area.

I would also advise against an OO approach. For some very small number of domains OO is the perfect solution. For most businesses, it's not. And Javascript is capable of so much more than just OO.

Answer (score 1):

The #1 problem (and, perhaps, the only problem) is search engine. It is not sure how well will your content be recognized/crawalble/searchable.  The underyling cause is that the search engine is not necessarily going to understand your content (since it is only revealed once Javascript gets executed).

Other than that, it is a great approach. I tried it several times and it works great (assuming you're not intimidated by Javascript). The resulting web-site is usually much more responsive than traditional web-sites since the server -> client traffic is quite small - only the raw data is transmitted. All the UI stuff is generated, by Javascript, on the client side.

Comment: I would not advise this approach for common 'websites'. For complex, data driven, domain specific web-applications however it's the Holy Grail.